# Associating a flow to a managed package (hypothetical)

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package, connected-apps, isv

As a Salesforce partner, I have two ways in which I can deliver solutions to my client.

1. Via a Managed Package from the AppExchange
2. Metadata via the API from a Connected App

In this scenario, the client has already installed the managed package which gives them access to get started with our product.

Simultaneously, our client can request flows from our app to be deployed into their environment. When this happens, is it possible to tie the flow that they received from our connected app to the managed package that was installed so it is now being referenced in 1 central location (IE view components view under Installed Packages)

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot add components to a managed package inside a subscriber org, full stop.

Answer (score 1):

As David mentioned: no.

The way around this is to deliver code outside the Managed Package or [Package Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/publish_extensions.htm).